# save woocommerce billing custom field in database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added one custom field in woocommerce billing fields..please check this bellow code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {
   $fields['duplicate_billing_address'] = array(

        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => __('Duplicate Billing Address to Shipping Address', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
     );

    return $fields;
}
```

How to save this custom field value in database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save on the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook. You can check out my tutorial on [custom WooCommerce checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/517/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) for more details.

```
// save the extra field when checkout is processed
function kia_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order_id, $posted ){
    if( isset( $posted['duplicate_billing_address'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_duplicate_billing_address', 'yes' );
    } else {
         update_post_meta( $order_id, '_duplicate_billing_address', 'no' );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'kia_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: But here , I added this custom field on edit billing address page(test.addpronetwork.com/flexotech-eCommerce/my-account/edit-address/billing/)not on checkout page(test.addpronetwork.com/flexotech-eCommerce/checkout/).. I think your code will work on checkout page.